# Image not visible during table export to MS WORD in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-word

I have the following code with me to export table present on aspx page with id "UserDetails".
When I export this table to **MS Excel** file images with absolute path are visible but when I export the table to **MS WORD (.doc)** file then the same images are not visible.

I searched a lot on net but nothing was helpful.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

```
  protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WORK_ORDER.doc");
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Charset = "";
    EnableViewState = false;

    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter html = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(writer);
    UserDetails.RenderControl(html);
    Response.Write(writer);
    Response.End();
```

}

Comment: What is the image url you got in Excel? copy the url and open the same in browser and see the problem :)

Comment: I had also tested this way and image is present and visible on browser on passing the same url.